# How to extract list of values into rows from XML using XQuery?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an XQuery as under

```
DECLARE @x XML
SELECT @x = '<PartnerEmails>
<Email>a@xxxx.com</Email>
<Email>b@xxxx.com</Email>
</PartnerEmails>'
SELECT @x.query('data(PartnerEmails/Email)').value('.','varchar(100)') AS Val
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Val
a@xxxx.com b@xxxx.com
```

**Expected Output**

```
a@xxxx.com
b@xxxx.com
```

i.e. In two different rows.

How to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT 
    node.value('.','varchar(100)') AS Val
FROM
    @x.nodes('/PartnerEmails/Email') AS PE(Node)
```

Since you have multiple nodes inside `<PartnerEmails>`, you need to use the `.nodes()` function to create an "inline" table of XML fragments - each "row" in that table contains one `<Email>` node which you can then query on (and extract the contents of the XML node).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @x XML
SELECT @x = '<PartnerEmails>
<Email>a@xxxx.com</Email>
<Email>b@xxxx.com</Email>
</PartnerEmails>'

SELECT   ColumnValue.value('.','varchar(1000)')  as Val            
FROM @x.nodes('/PartnerEmails/Email') as Table1(ColumnValue)
```

Comment: Great answer, as it provides both input data definition as well as recipe. @Asif, shall we update answer one and get rid of this one? It is nearly a duplicate, plus the first one has an explanation.