# Using the XQUERY node function to extract values into rows

Tags: oracle, xquery-sql, oracle-xml-db

My question is identical to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948870/how-to-extract-list-of-values-into-rows-from-xml-using-xquery) but instead of SQL Server I am using Oracle 12.1.

I would like to extract all the name elements from the following xml document:

```
<ci5>
   <employee>
      <name>George Cowley</name>  
      <salary via="B">80000</salary>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <name>William Bodie</name>  
      <salary via="C">40000</salary>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <name>Ray Doyle</name>  
      <salary via="C">40000</salary>
   </employee>
</ci5>
```

The output I want is three separate rows such as:

```
<name>George Cowley</name>
<name>William Bodie</name>
<name>Ray Doyle</name>
```

Using the following queries

```
SELECT XMLQUERY('ci5/employee/name' 
                  PASSING BY VALUE XMLTYPE.CREATEXML('<ci5><employee><name>George Cowley</name><salary via="B">80000</salary></employee><employee><name>William Bodie</name><salary via="C">40000</salary></employee><employee><name>Ray Doyle</name><salary via="C">40000</salary></employee></ci5>') RETURNING CONTENT) x
   FROM dual;  

 SELECT XMLQUERY('for $i in /ci5
                 return $i/employee/name'
                 PASSING BY VALUE XMLTYPE.CREATEXML('<ci5><employee><name>George Cowley</name><salary via="B">80000</salary></employee><employee><name>William Bodie</name><salary via="C">40000</salary></employee><employee><name>Ray Doyle</name><salary via="C">40000</salary></employee></ci5>') RETURNING CONTENT) x
   FROM dual;
```

the names are shown, but the output is all on one line:

```
<name>George Cowley</name><name>William Bodie</name><name>Ray Doyle</name>
```

It looks like I need to use the `NODE` function but I don't how to use it within an Oracle context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database-features/xmldb/overview/xmldb-bpwp-12cr1-1964809.pdf) Oracle white paper answered the question, I needed to use [XMLTABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions268.htm#SQLRF06232) which

> ...maps the result of an XQuery evaluation into relational rows and
>   columns...

Changing my query to use XMLTABLE

```
 SELECT x.ename
   FROM XMLTABLE('/ci5/employee/name'                 
                 PASSING XMLTYPE.CREATEXML('<ci5><employee><name>George Cowley</name><salary via="B">80000</salary></employee><employee><name>William Bodie</name><salary via="C">40000</salary></employee><employee><name>Ray Doyle</name><salary via="C">40000</salary></employee></ci5>') 
                 COLUMNS ename VARCHAR2(30) PATH '/name') x
```

gives the following output in SQL Developer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need any xquery for this.  A simple xpath expression should suffice.  Here are two options.  The first returns an XML sequence (separate xml nodes), the second returns as table rows:

```
    WITH test AS
      (SELECT xmltype('<ci5>   
    <employee>      
    <name>George Cowley</name>        
    <salary via="B">80000</salary>   
    </employee>   
    <employee>      
    <name>William Bodie</name>        
    <salary via="C">40000</salary>   
    </employee>   
    <employee>      
    <name>Ray Doyle</name>        
    <salary via="C">40000</salary>   
    </employee>
    </ci5>  ') data
      FROM dual
      )
    SELECT xmlsequence(extract(data,'/ci5/employee/name')) FROM test

WITH test AS
      (SELECT xmltype('<ci5>   
    <employee>      
    <name>George Cowley</name>        
    <salary via="B">80000</salary>   
    </employee>   
    <employee>      
    <name>William Bodie</name>        
    <salary via="C">40000</salary>   
    </employee>   
    <employee>      
    <name>Ray Doyle</name>        
    <salary via="C">40000</salary>   
    </employee>
    </ci5>  ') data
      FROM dual
      )
    SELECT extract(value(d), '*') AS name
    FROM test,
      TABLE(xmlsequence(extract(data, '/ci5/employee/name'))) d
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the response, I didn't want to fill up my question with cruft but the reason for using XQUERY is that I am getting up to speed with it because extract(XML) is deprecated @ 11GR2 see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions060.htm#SQLRF00640